# Is it possible to open the console in a jar file without the command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, jar

I have a .jar file that uses System.out and similar functions. Normally, I would use either Eclipse or the Windows Command Prompt. However, our school does not give us access to the command prompt and I can't use Eclipse.

Is there a way to do it without an IDE or the command line?

Answer (score 1):

The use of STDOUT and STDERR for debugging purpose should be avoided. First it is difficult to filter the output, second the performance could be affected.

The most used methods to log the debugging information in Java is log4j and java.util.logging.

It is also possible to redirect the STDOUT with [System.setOut()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29), with log4j, etc...

Answer (score 0):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454748/how-can-an-executable-jar-file-be-run-without-the-command-prompt)

Another suggestion would be to create a batch file that runs it. You can do this by opening notepad and save what would normally be in the cmd prompt with a .bat extension. (Unless your school blocks this too.)

Hope these help.